Mindstorms EV3 brick doesn't start up
When attempting to start your Mindstorms EV3 brick, the light turns red briefly and then turns amber (yellow or orange?) and stays that way indefinitely. The screen does not turn on at all. Any ideas on how to correct this issue?

If you hold down the right button while powering on the EV3, does it go into update mode (screen will say "updating...")?

No. I just tried it. It behaves exactly the same. The light goes red briefly and then changes color and the screen stays off.

Are the batteries dead?

The batteries are not dead. Six fresh, new AA batteries.

If any sensors or motors are plugged in, I would try unplugging them.
If that doesn't work either, I would contact LEGO customer support.
